# Why do UE4 specs crash when certain variables are passed into the `It()` lambda?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

When writing UE4 specs, I find that sometimes a value that is passed-in to a lambda causes a crash or unpredictable result, while other times it does not.

For example, calling any method on the `Matcher` object inside `It()` in the example below will cause a crash (all the values are garbage data when I inspect them in the Rider debugger):

```cpp
void FPF2AbilityBoostRuleOptionMatcherSpec::Define()
{
    Describe(TEXT("when there are no rule options"), [=, this]()
    {
        const TArray<FPF2AbilityBoostRuleOption> RuleOptions = {};

        Describe(TEXT("CanApplyAbilityBoost()"), [=, this]()
        {
            FPF2AbilityBoostRuleOptionMatcher Matcher(RuleOptions);

            It(TEXT("returns `false` for all abilities"), [=, this, &Matcher]()
            {
                for (const auto& AbilityScoreType : TEnumRange<EPF2CharacterAbilityScoreType>())
                {
                    TestFalse(
                        FString::Format(TEXT("CanApplyAbilityBoost({0})"), { PF2EnumUtils::ToString(AbilityScoreType)}),
                        Matcher.CanApplyAbilityBoost(AbilityScoreType)
                    );
                }
            });
        });
        // ...
    });
    // ...
}
```

Switching it to pass-by-value results in an IDE error, but it compiles and crashes the same as if I was using a reference:

```cpp
void FPF2AbilityBoostRuleOptionMatcherSpec::Define()
{
    Describe(TEXT("when there are no rule options"), [=, this]()
    {
        const TArray<FPF2AbilityBoostRuleOption> RuleOptions = {};

        Describe(TEXT("CanApplyAbilityBoost()"), [=, this]()
        {
            FPF2AbilityBoostRuleOptionMatcher Matcher(RuleOptions);

            It(TEXT("returns `false` for all abilities"), [=, this, Matcher]()
            {
                for (const auto& AbilityScoreType : TEnumRange<EPF2CharacterAbilityScoreType>())
                {
                    TestFalse(
                        FString::Format(TEXT("CanApplyAbilityBoost({0})"), { PF2EnumUtils::ToString(AbilityScoreType)}),
                        // Next line gets highlighted in red in Rider but compiles. Error is:
                        // Cannot convert 'this' argument from type 'FPF2AbilityBoostRuleOptionMatcher const' to type
                        // 'FPF2AbilityBoostRuleOptionMatcher': function is missing 'const' qualifier`
                        Matcher.CanApplyAbilityBoost(AbilityScoreType)
                    );
                }
            });
        });
        // ...
    });
    // ...
}
```

This works, though (but the `Matcher` has to be constructed in every test case):

```cpp
void FPF2AbilityBoostRuleOptionMatcherSpec::Define()
{
    Describe(TEXT("when there are no rule options"), [=, this]()
    {
        const TArray<FPF2AbilityBoostRuleOption> RuleOptions = {};

        Describe(TEXT("CanApplyAbilityBoost()"), [=, this]()
        {
            It(TEXT("returns `false` for all abilities"), [=, this]()
            {
                FPF2AbilityBoostRuleOptionMatcher Matcher(RuleOptions);

                for (const auto& AbilityScoreType : TEnumRange<EPF2CharacterAbilityScoreType>())
                {
                    TestFalse(
                        FString::Format(TEXT("CanApplyAbilityBoost({0})"), { PF2EnumUtils::ToString(AbilityScoreType)}),
                        Matcher.CanApplyAbilityBoost(AbilityScoreType)
                    );
                }
            });
            });
        });
        // ...
    });
    // ...
}
```

Why? Is the destructor getting called on this object for some reason before it's referenced?

Comment: Addressed, @JaMiT. A bit of kindness might go further :)

Comment: There's not really anything here that looks particularly crashy. Do you have optimisations on in the file? (Might explain why Matcher looks like it's filled with garbage). It might be something sketchy happening inside one of Matcher's constructors or even destructor. It could also be partially explained if `Descirbe` allows the passed function to be called later down the line once Matcher has gone out of scope. Although that still doesn't really explain why your second example crashes.

Comment: Check the documentation for `It()`. Your symptoms are a good match for documentation that says that the second parameter (your lambda) may be called after the execution of `It()` finishes; that the second parameter will be stored somewhere to be executed at a later time. This would be consistent with a sort of "lazy" definition, where the engine records how to generate the specs, but generates each layer of detail only as needed.

Comment: Thanks, @JaMiT! It's feeling a lot like the variables in the outer scope are getting stack allocated and then by the time they get used they're pointing at garbage memory. I'll see if I can dig deeper based on what you've pointed out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, the variables in the outer scope were getting stack allocated and then by the time they got used they were pointing at garbage memory. To avoid the crash, the variables must be declared `static`, which ensures the memory stays reserved for these values throughout run time.